# Java Storing Conditions By Generic Type

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, effective-java

I've been reading Effective Java and decided to try to put some of what I've learned into action.  I'm trying to effectively create a `Multimap<?, Condition<?> >`  where the wild card will be the same type for both the key and the value, but it will be different, distinct types.

Here is the item from the book I'm looking at: [Item 29](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=typesafe+heterogenous+containers&source=bl&ots=yXKoRfr3T3&sig=48S_WcIAsVEtm7jycTm-JtPyLB0&hl=en&ei=NYniTPXuNoOclgeX8cjjAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I'm not trying to fully replicate it.  I realize the big difference is the key does not represent the value directly as per the link.  In mine, the key represents the generic type of the value.

So I will do `mmap.put(Class<Integer>, ConditionMapping<Integer>)`
when I do the get I don't have the generic type of the ConditionMapping, so I get the unchecked cast warning.

I have a get method that I want to have the signature `<T> List<Condition <T> >(Class<T> type)`

Due to type erasure, is my only option to make sure the condition.value is of type T and building a new list of objects?

I could just ignore the unchecked cast warning, but I'm just trying not to.  Any suggestions?  Tips?  Tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to express that the two wildcards should capture the same type. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4390554/476716) for a similar situation and a number of possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your interface extend `Multimap<Void, Condition<?>>` it allows your user to call some of the methods that do not rely on type safety (e.g. containsKey) but not to add entries (bypassing your type-checked proxy methods) unless they use unchecked casts.

```
interface ConditionMapBase<T> extends Multimap<T, Condition<?>> {
}
interface ConditionMap extends ConditionMapBase<Void> {
    <T>boolean putCondition(T key, Condition<T> value);
    <T>Collection<Condition<T>> getConditions(T key);
}
class ConditionMapImpl
extends ForwardingMultimap<Void, Condition<?>>
implements ConditionMap {

    ConditionMapImpl() {
        delegate = HashMultimap.create();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected Multimap<Void, Condition<?>> delegate() {
        return (Multimap<Void, Condition<?>>) (Multimap<?, ?>) delegate;
    }
    private final Multimap<Object, Condition<?>> delegate;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> Collection<Condition<T>> getConditions(T key) {
        return (Collection<Condition<T>>) (Collection<?>) ((ConditionMapBase<T>) this).get(key);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> boolean putCondition(T key, Condition<T> value) {
        return ((ConditionMapBase<T>) this).put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a MyClass and then pass your own type to it, and ecapsulate the Multimap inside that. Template impossibilities in Java can often be solved by adding another layer, so to speak, and templating a class around what you really want, since you can get a "T" type that way, which you can then use for Lists or Maps, and guarantee that it is the same for multiple templates from then on.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting you.  Are you saying something like defining an IntCondition or a StringCondition?  Where I do IntCondition extends Condition<Integer> ? Or  are you saying make Condition take a type or get the type from the instance created? Or make a separate container for each type?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a step in the right direction.

```
<Multimap<Class<?>, Condition<?>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will permit `put(String.class, new Condition<Integer>())`